# one post per term taxonomx

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy

I need some help, again.

I use this query:

```
$tax = get_the_terms($id, 'coupon_category');
                    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
                    query_posts( array(
                        'post_type' => APP_POST_TYPE,
                        'post_status' => 'publish',
                        'posts_per_page' => 4,
                        'tax_query' => array( 
                        'relation' => 'AND',
                            array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'coupon_category', // Taxonomy
                            'field'    => 'slug',
                            'terms'    => $tax[0]->slug, // Your category slug
                            ),
                            array(
                            'taxonomy' => APP_TAX_STORE,
                            'field'    => 'slug',
                            'terms'    => $term->slug,
                            'operator' => 'NOT IN',
                            ),
                        ),                      
                    ) );
```

I know need a solution to only show one post from each Taxonomy term `APP_TAX_STORE`. Tried some solutions from this userfull forum but non worked for me.

Comment: I have more than 2000 terms ;-) and don't want to post one from each only 4 but do not want to repeat one term.

Comment: @SallyCJ could you explain to me more specific?

Comment: still looking for a solution

Comment: And still looking now?..

Comment: yes I am still looking

Comment: I deleted my answer because you mentioned via the answer comments that you've found a solution. All the best.